# Is there a polyfill for converting css flex shorthand to longhand in order to support IE11?

Tags: css, flexbox, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

Is there a polyfill for converting Flexbox **flex:** shorthand property to their comparable longhand properties in order to support IE11?

After doing some research I discovered a few flexbox polyfills but none of them support the flex: shorthand property.

If there isn't a polyfill that supports flex shorthand, I will have to manually replace them all with the longhand version.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

For the time being I created this mixin to provide a fallback:

```
/*

 Mixin for IE11 fallback for shorthand flex property.

 EXAMPLE USAGE:

    .grid {
       flex: 1 0 100%; // todo: replace this with below
    }

    .grid {
      @include flexIEFallback(1 0 100%);
    }

    OUTPUT:

    .grid {
       flex-grow: 1;
       flex-shrink: 0;
       flex-basis: 100%;
    }

*/
@mixin flexIEFallback($flex-list) {
  // this is the shorthand
  //  flex: $flex-list;

  // IE11 fallback for shorthand prop flex
  @if length($flex-list) == 1 {
    @if $flex-list == (auto) {
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-shrink: 1;
      flex-basis: auto;
    }
    @if $flex-list == (initial) {
      flex-grow: 0;
      flex-shrink: 1;
      flex-basis: auto;
    }
    @if $flex-list == (none) {
      flex-grow: 0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      flex-basis: auto;
    }
    @if $flex-list == (unset) {
      flex-grow: unset;
      flex-shrink: unset;
      flex-basis: unset;
    }
    @if $flex-list == (inherit) {
      flex-grow: inherit;
      flex-shrink: inherit;
      flex-basis: inherit;
    } @else {
      flex-grow: $flex-list;
    }
  }

  @if length($flex-list) > 1 {
    @for $item from 1 through length($flex-list) {
      $index: index($flex-list, $item);

      @if $index == 1 {
        flex-grow: $item;
      }

      @if $index == 2 {
        flex-shrink: $item;
      }

      @if $index == 3 {
        flex-basis: $item;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I try to search for the polyfill for converting CSS flex shorthand to longhand but I did not get any relevant polyfill for it. It looks like you need to continue with your manual approach.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this ponyfill instead of going the polyfill route.

https://github.com/jhildenbiddle/css-vars-ponyfill

It may not fit your exact need since adding your example but I have used it to for similiar situations before to allow for shorthand properties to be defined for css classes and maintain compatibility with older browsers that did not support the  css shorthand syntax.